# Regex Name Retrieval

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to write a simple Regex expression that retrieves names for me based on the presence of a character string at the end of a line.

I've been successful at isolating each of these patterns using pythex in my data set, but I have been unable to match them as a conditional group.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Data Example

> Mark Samson: CA

> Sam Smith: US

> Dawn Watterton: CA

> Neil Shughar: CA

> Fennial Fontaine: US

I want to be able to create a regex expression that uses the end of each line as the condition of the group match - i.e I want a list of those who live in the US from this dataset. I have used each of these expressions in isolation and it seems to work in matching what I am looking for. What I need is help in making the below a grouped search.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

> `([US]$)([A-Z][a-z]+)`

Comment: You want `.+?(?=:\s*US$)`

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/fIx3MK/1 work? Judging from the inputs you gave, you should be able to capture the name from the group.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following?

`(\w+[ \w]*): US`

Answer (score 0):

You say "*I have been unable to match them as a conditional group*", but you are not using any conditional groups. `([US]$)([A-Z][a-z]+)` is an example of a pattern that never matches any string as it matches `U` or `S`, then requires an end of string, and then matches an uppercase ASCII letter and one or more ASCII lowercase letters.

You want any string from start till a colon, whitespaces, and `US` *substring* at the end of string.

Hence, use

```
.+?(?=:\s*US$)
^(.+?):\s*US$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKpLdn/1). *Details*:

- `.+?` - one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=:\s*US$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `:`, zero or more whitespaces, `US` string and the end of string.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xHPPNB):

```py
import re
texts = ["Mark Samson: CA", "Sam Smith: US", "Dawn Watterton: CA", "Neil Shughar: CA", "Fennial Fontaine: US"]
for text in texts:
    match = re.search(r".+?(?=:\s*US$)", text)
    if match:
        print(match.group()) # With r"^(.+?):\s*US$" regex, use match.group(1) here
```

Output:

```
Sam Smith
Fennial Fontaine
```